# Selected ContentOffSet of a UIScrollView display from NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

i m working on quotesApp. there is a favorite tableView which display the favorite quotes in a `UITableView`.   
Clicking on the row it goes to detailView which display all the favorite quotes in a `UIScrollView`.  
 which start from the first index of a NSArray. i want to display the selected index in a UIScrollView and then with swipe it display all the other object in Array. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use another UITableView, which each cell is a NSArray row. It will be faster and smarter than using a scrollview !

Comment: actually requirement is uIScrollView actually i want to display all the row in a UIScrollview with scrolling

Comment: you can also display the data in tableview, why not use tableview then? you can set the seperator to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone, and it will look like a plain scrollview

Comment: with this Horizantal scrolling can be possible